# How do I configure additional Thunderbird unified folders?

Tags: thunderbird

Can Thunderbird by configured for new unified folders other than the ones provided by default?

For example, my profile has a "Spam" unified folder, but the only Spam folder showing up there of my ~10 IMAP accounts is one from Gmail. How can I get my other 9 IMAP Spam folders to show up under that node in the Unified tree?

Another example, say I have a folder per account called "Receipts". Is it possible to setup a unified folder for that?

I have tried marking folders as Favorites and even added folders to "Search" to the unified folders. The first didn't help and the second caused all folders to be listed but not as a sub-folder under the unified node in the tree. However, my "Spam" node doesn't appear to be a true unified folder, but a shortcut to the Gmail folder.

Answer (score 4):

You can select which folders are included in each of the Unified Folders:

1. Right-click on a Unified Folder
2. Select "Properties"
   [image: Unified Folder context menu]
3. Select the "Choose..." button next to "Select the folders to search:"
   [image: Properties of a Unified Folder]
4. Select the folders to which to be included in this Unified Folder.
5. Select "Match all messages" or define more filters.

A Unified Folder is actually kind of a special Saved Search. So yes, if you have a folder per account called "Receipts", it is possible to setup a unified folder for that:

1. Right-click on any non-Unified Folder. This can be an account's base folder or any sub-folder). I recommend starting with a sub-folder, otherwise you probably have to de-select a bunch of folders in Step 4 that you don't want searched.
2. Select "Search Messages..."
3. Select the "Save as Search Folder" button at the bottom
   [image]
4. Select the folders to which to be included in this Search Folder. This is almost same as above, except you have to tell Thunderbird where you want that Search Folder saved. I usually select "Local Folders".
5. Select "Match all messages" or define more filters.
6. Optional: Right-click the created Search Folder and add it to your Favourite Folders.
   NB: I have "All", "Unified" and "Favourite" selected under View > Folders. The order in which you select those is relevant: the last selected is added on top. So if you want "Favourite" (top), "Unified" and then "All" (bottom) in that order in your Folder Pane, you'd have to select "All", "Unified" and then "Favourite" in that order.

Answer (score -1):

By using local folders, you can have mail from multiple accounts saved in specific locations. For example, I created local folders for *Courses*, *Employment* etc. Then I created some *Filter* rules: e.g., if the *Subject* contains "Amazon', then move to *Finances, Products & Purchases*. Other mail can be moved manually by drag-and-drop.

[You can also change the destination folder for each account's incoming email to the same folder.](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Moving_your_mail_storage_location_(Thunderbird))

[image: Local Folders]